# CSS not displaying properly in Internet Explorer & opera

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have made nice spinning wheel with CSS and it renders perfectly in mozilla firefox, chrome, safari, android stock browser you name it.

THe only exceptions are Internet Explorer and Opera. The render it very ugly and I can't seem to find where it the root cause is that it doens't render properly because what I have read I'm following the instructions properly...

See below for the difference:
[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/cyLrm/2

The problem mainly lies I think in the following CSS Code:

```
background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(75% 20%, circle closest-corner, #ffffff, #ff0d0d 100px);
background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(65% 50%, circle closest-corner, #ffffff, #ff0d0d 100px);
background-image: -o-radial-gradient(75% 20%, circle closest-corner, #ffffff, #ff0d0d 100px);
background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(75% 20%, circle closest-corner, #ffffff, #ff0d0d 100px);
background-image: radial-gradient(75% 20%, circle closest-corner, #ffffff, #ff0d0d 100px);
```

Also, if someone knows a way to make the css animation work under IE I would be very grateful.

Comment: ie .. always been a headache to webdevelopers :/ You wouldn't get a common code to work with all browsers, probably you will have to load different CSS in according to browser! (Javascript has a facility to know client's browser and its version)

Comment: Yes I know... but I'd like to know what kind of css or filters for IE. And for Opera, the above code "*should*" work, but doesn't... and I was wondering if anyone knows why opera behaves this way.

Comment: not sure if the property that you are expecting even works for IE, but I still wonder why opera behaves so weird (like IE) sometimes..

Comment: @InfantProgrammer'Aravind' That is what I thought too... usually opera follows suit with the best browsers, but sometimes it just goes the IE way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what i know in Internet Explorer 8-9 there is not support for gradient backgrounds and animations. I don't know about opera you should check the specs.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, IE is terrible for implementing CSS3. Have you added a DOCTYPE to your HTML? This may fix the IE issue. As far as Opera goes, I don't have a clue whether the DOCTYPE fix will work.